# Error::Plugin not allowed in config.xml - Cordova/Phonegap

Tags: cordova, windows-phone-8, phonegap-plugins

I am trying to create my first plugin in wp8, but I am getting this error

> *Plugin not allowed in **config.xml**.*

What am I doing wrong?

In config.xml

```
  <feature name="Echo">
        <param name="wp-package" value="com.example.echo.plugins.Echo"/>
  </feature>
```

In echo.js

```
window.echo = function (str, callback) {
    cordova.exec(callback, function (err) {
        callback('Nothing to echo.');
    }, "com.example.echo.plugins.Echo", "echo", [str]);
};
```

In echo.cs

```
using WPCordovaClassLib.Cordova;
using WPCordovaClassLib.Cordova.Commands;
using WPCordovaClassLib.Cordova.JSON;

namespace com.example.echo.plugins
{
    class Echo : BaseCommand
    {
        public void echo(string options)
        {
...
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In **echo.js**

only Class Name has to be called and not the full package.
As below:

```
window.echo = function (str, callback) {
    cordova.exec(callback, function (err) {
        callback('Nothing to echo.');
    }, "Echo", "echo", [str]);
};
```