# How to access image file from HTML or Javascript for Windows Phone

Tags: javascript, c#, windows-phone-8

I have a requirement in wp8, where the picture selected by the user needs to be shown in the browser. To browse and select the photo, I am using photo chooser task.

I am able to get the physical location of the selected image, but on passing the same to JavaScript from c# its not displaying the image.

On googling came across the following link [How to access isolated storage file from HTML or Javascript for Windows Phone and PhoneGap Application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26041220/how-to-access-isolated-storage-file-from-html-or-javascript-for-windows-phone-an/29032071#29032071) But it did not solve my issue.

For reference, the location of the image I am using was:

> C:\Data\Users\DefApps\AppData{FA586990-6E21-0130-BF9E-3C075409010C}\Local\sample_photo_00.jpg

This is my Javascript code:

```
function myPicture(data) {
    document.getElementById("capturedImage").src = data.imageUri;
    alert("data.imageUri   " + document.getElementById("capturedImage").src );
    var width = data.imageWidth;
    var height = data.imageHeight;

    alert("image width" + width );
    alert("image height" + height );
}
```

And this is my C# code:

```
StorageFolder localFolder = ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder; 
string[] picList = Directory.GetFiles(localFolder.Path, "*.jpg");

foreach (string DeleteFile in picList) { 
    File.Delete(DeleteFile); 
}

StorageFile storageFile = await localFolder.CreateFileAsync(fileName, CreationCollisionOption.ReplaceExisting);
using (Stream outputStream = await storageFile.OpenStreamForWriteAsync())
{
    await file.CopyToAsync(outputStream);
}

send (storageFile.Path);
```

Now send function should add MyHTML in picture.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! There are some things wrong with your post - including the code formatting (see [editing help](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) for into); you have called a code sample "Java code", but it is Javascript (quite different) and I don't understand the bit starting "I tried the above" and ending "image source". That makes it hard to help you - to understand what you have done so far and what hasn't worked. Please make sure you've read [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) & try to edit your post so it gets more help. Good luck!

Comment: Sorry, my fault

Let me rephrase the question,

I have a requirement in wp8, where the picture selected by the user needs to be shown in the browser.

To browse and select the photo, I am using photo chooser task,  I am able to get the physical location of the selected image, on passing the same to JavaScript from c# its not displaying the image,
On googling came across the following link

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26041220/how-to-access-isolated-storage-file-from-html-or-javascript-for-windows-phone-an/29032071#29032071

But it was of no help, thanks in advance

Comment: OK - yes - that's much better.  Use the [edit link](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/29034855/edit) to put all that into your question above the Javascript code(***replacing*** what's already there) and I think you will get better results (I'm not a C# expert, but there are lots here).  Also - add the javascript and C# tags while you're editing to attract more specialist answers.

Comment: Just seen you've done that, but deleted the code.  I advise put the code back and add the tags and then this will be a good question.

Comment: Thank you Richard for every thing.

Comment: No problem - I hope someone comes along that can answer it for you (unfortunately I'm not an expert in this task).

Comment: "Now send function should add MyHTML in picture."? Maybe you mean "add picture to my html"?

Answer (score 0):

You can call JavaScript function from C# by [WebBrowser.InvokeScript](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/ff402838(v=vs.105).aspx) and send image in **args** parameter. But **args** is string(s), so you will have to encode your image to string using some algorithm... Base64 for example:

```
string ImageToBase64String(Image image)
{
    using (MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream())
    {
        image.Save(stream, image.RawFormat);
        return Convert.ToBase64String(stream.ToArray());
    }
}
```

You will get some long string like this `iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAUAAAAFCAYAAACNbyblAAAAHElEQVQI12P4//8/w38GIAXDIBKE0DHxgljNBAAO9TXL0Y4OHwAAAABJRU5ErkJggg==`

On other side - in the JavaScript function you calling you will get that Base64 string and use it like this as **src** attribute of **img** element:

```
<img src="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAUAAAAFCAYAAACNbyblAAAAHElEQVQI12P4//8/w38GIAXDIBKE0DHxgljNBAAO9TXL0Y4OHwAAAABJRU5ErkJggg==" />
```

More info about [data uri scheme](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_URI_scheme).

**UPDATE**: The easer solution. I think you can send your image path, width and height:

```
ImageProperties properties = await storageFile.Properties.GetImagePropertiesAsync();
webBrowser.InvokeScript("myPicture", storageFile.Path, (string)properties.Width, (string)properties.Height);
```

---

```
function myPicture(src, width, height) {
    document.getElementById("capturedImage").src = src;
    alert("data.imageUri   " + document.getElementById("capturedImage").src );

    alert("image width" + width );
    alert("image height" + height );
}
```